# Reference for Lorax 35-day calendar

Tags: the-lorax, dr.-seuss

My daughter is still in love with [*The Lorax* (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1482459/), although (luckily for me) we don't watch it as often as we used to. Today we had it on TV, when I realized there was a calendar Ted's room, and I thought it could help me identify the timeline of the movie ([related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63943/38571))... silly me, I thought it would help me, instead it left me even more puzzled:

[image: Image from The Lorax]

Here's a detail of the calendar where you can see a month of October with 35  (or 34-and-a-half) days:

[image: Lorax's Calendar detail]

I thought it could be a homage to The Lorax or a different Dr. Seuss' work, but I didn't find any reference in the book about this long October; and searching online I only get information about two types of calendars that don't look related to this one: the [5-Week Leap Month Calendar](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/5-Week_Leap_Month_Calendar) and the [Bonavian Calendar](http://myweb.ecu.edu/mccartyr/bonavian.html).

Is this 35-days month based on any of Dr. Seuss' stories? Or is it a cross reference to a different book/movie?

Comment: Fascinating detail! The 12 1/2th of October? WOT? Too funny.